# Cannot convert type "unityengine.vector3" to "float"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the camera move back to the player if the camera is not in the place where it stops but I keep getting the error in the title. Here is my code:

```cs
public float minPos = 0.3234783f;
public float maxPos = 40f;

Vector3 tempPos;
public float playerPos;

private void Update() 
{
    playerPos = GameObject.Find ("Player").transform.position;
    tempPos   = transform.position;
    tempPos.z = -10f;

    if (transform.position.x < minPos)
         tempPos.x = minPos;
    else tempPos.x = playerPos;

    transform.position = tempPos;
}
```

I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if this is a really dumb mistake.

Comment: it's because you cannot convert type “unityengine.vector3” to “float”.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here `playerPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;`

`transform.position;` is `Vector3` not `float`. `playerPos` is defined as `float` so you can't save `Vector3` to `float`.

Change

`public float playerPos;`

to

`public Vector3 playerPos;`

And also change

```
tempPos.x = playerPos;
```

to
 `tempPos.x = playerPos.x;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line, which the IDE should have told you:

```
playerPos = GameObject.Find ("Player").transform.position;
```

`playerPos` is type `float` but `position` property is type `Vector3` and there's no conversion between them. You could make `playerPos` into a `Vector3` to fix it and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Ok so now I have the same exact error on line 23 :\

Comment: @user6210476 same reason there. `tempPos.x = playerPos;` doesnt work because playerPos is now a vector. you have to rewrite your code.